# react native stylesheet.create function is returning mapped numbers instead of style rules

Tags: reactjs, react-native, stylesheet

I have a simple stylesheet declared at the bottom of my react component.

```
const styles = StyleSheet.create({
start:{
 flex:1
},
text:{
 color: "red",
 fontSize: 24,
 flex: 1
},
separator:{
 height: 2,
 backgroundColor: "white"
}
});
```

When i try to refernce any of these styles, I get back a number instead of the style rules.

```
export default class ShowGallery extends Component{
  render(){
     return(
       <View>
         <Text style={styles.text}>Test </Text>
       </View>
    )
 }
}
```

here styles.text is returning 193? By the way i'm using react native version 37.0

Answer (score 1):

This is actually a performance enhancement of `StyleSheet`
It can be very expensive to transfer the styles from the JS side to the native side, by using `StyleSheet.create` the styles are sent across the bridge ahead of time, and 'cached' by the native side.

The individual numbers are then used as a reference between the JS side and the native side, to know which styles to use.

Answer (score 1):

It's normal behavior if you use `StyleSheet.create()`. If you need to access style object you can use `StyleSheet.flatten(styles.text)`. Link to [documentation](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/stylesheet.html#flatten).